# Wireless connection is very slow

Tags: wireless, networking, kubuntu

I installed [Kubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu) on my new HP-15 laptop that I just got. Initially the wireless connection was working well, but about two days ago I noticed a decline in the speed of the wireless connection. When I ping the router I'm getting results greater than 500 ms and sometimes I get 1700 ms whereas if I'm on a wired connection I get 0.4,0.3 and that means it's as fast as it's supposed to be.

I never experienced the issue when I used Kubuntu on my old laptop, so I don't know what caused this as I didn't change any network settings. Even my colleagues in the office who use Windows have never complained of this.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: don't know what happened because i tried lots of things i saw online like disabling the n...and now it seems to be working but i'll still run the script and post the output

Comment: the speed has dropped again but here is the output from the script http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8178092/ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
echo "options rt2800pci nohwcrypt=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rt2800pci
sudo modprobe -v rt2800pci
```

that command changes encryption from hardware to software.

Do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

(this will create or edit a configuration file that will override the default power management behavior) and enter the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

above exit0, then save gedit, close.

Set your wireless settings in network manager to match the screenshots.
[image: wireless settings]
[image: IPV6 settings]

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a lot of dropped packets as well? I found that I had a lot of problems after moving to my apartment building. I used an Android app on my phone called WiFi Analyzer which shows the strengths of all the nearby wifi signals, as well as the channels they are running on. The suggestion I'd heard was to run your wifi on channel 1, 6, or 11, whichever has the least overlap from other nearby wireless routers.

The second thing I did was get a dual band router, since almost no one nearby is using those nearby frequencies. That helped me the most and all my devices now are running on 5Ghz (except the chromecast, which only runs on 2.4GHz). No more connectivity issues.

Comment: don't know what happened because i tried lots of things i saw online like disabling the n...and now it seems to be working...Thanks for trying