# driver management software dosen't show anything(Kubuntu)

Tags: wireless, drivers, kubuntu

I was having some problems with my wifi and i decided to check the drivers i have installed using the driver management software in the system settings in kubuntu.but for some reason it dosen't display anything or is there another way to easily check the drivers on kubuntu because i really need to solve my wifi issues before i go back to school.Thanks

Here is a screenshot of what shows up

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Driver Manager only shows **proprietary alternatives** to currently installed drivers.

If your WiFi card doesn't show up there, check the producers support website for a Linux driver.

Comment: ok i found it is Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe...but i think other drivers are supposed to show in the interface.any idea why it is still empty?

Comment: What specific devices are you talking about?

Comment: As for your Wifi driver: I got the same WiFi card. There is no better driver, at least not for newer Linux kernel versions. I, too, have problems with it, but you can't change it.

Comment: ok thanks for the help because i'm really having problems with my wifi,it dosen't connect at all and even if it manages to connect it's very slow compared to the wired cable...please if you have any suggestion please post here http://askubuntu.com/questions/517234/wireless-connection-is-very-slow...Thanks